# R get.hist.quote index name

Tags: r, date, time-series

I used get.hist.quote to import stock data in R. However I cannot seem to `colname` the index Date `as.Date`.

Here's the code:

```
SPX.prices = get.hist.quote(instrument="^gspc", start="1980-01-01", quote = c("Open", "High", "Low", "AdjClose"), provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01", compression="d", retclass="zoo")
```

Here's the output of the first rows with colnames

```
           Open  High  Low   AdjClose
1980-01-02 107.9 108.4 105.3    105.8
1980-01-03 105.8 106.1 103.3    105.2
1980-01-04 105.2 107.1 105.1    106.5
1980-01-07 106.5 107.8 105.8    106.8
1980-01-08 106.8 109.3 106.3    109.0
1980-01-09 109.0 111.1 108.4    109.0
```

1. So how do I assign "Date" to the index column?
2. How do I reformat the Date column in zoo?
3. How can I resort the Date in decreasing/descending order?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object:

```
library(tseries)
SPX.prices <- get.hist.quote(instrument="^gspc", start="1980-01-01",
                             quote = c("Open", "High", "Low", "AdjClose"), 
                             provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01", 
                             compression="d", retclass="zoo")
```

1. The index column is of class `Date`. You can access the information with `time` or `index` from the `zoo` package.

   ```
   class(time(SPX.prices))
   # [1] "Date"

   library(zoo)
   class(index(SPX.prices))
   # [1] "Date"
   ```
2. Reformat the dates:

   You shouldn't change the index of a `zoo` object, but store your information in a data frame:

   ```
   dat <- cbind(Date = time(SPX.prices), as.data.frame(SPX.prices))

   # new format
   dat$Date2 <- format(dat$Date, "%d %B %Y")
   # [1] "02 January 1980" "03 January 1980" "04 January 1980" ...
   ```
3. You can sort your data frame along `Date`:

   ```
   # ascending
   dat[order(dat$Date), ]
   # descending
   dat[order(dat$Date, decreasing = TRUE), ]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. How can I sort the index?

Comment: Thanks @Sven_Hohenstein but I'm getting the error that "Error in order(SPX.prices$Date, decreasing = TRUE) : 
  argument 1 is not a vector"

Comment: @user3308813 This only works with the data frame representation. You have to use the object `dat`.

Comment: @user3308813 The command returns an ordered data frame. You have to assign it, e.g., `dat <- dat[order(dat$Date), ]`.

Comment: Nevermind @Sven_Hohenstein I think I got it really appreciate your help and support!